# Creating a new wordpress post from twitter tweets

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter

I'd like to build an application that, on interval, it checks for tweets containing a particular hashtag, and creates an individual Wordpress post for each tweet that it finds.

What is the best way to do this? Are there existing plugins/tools available, or should I write my own custom plugin?

I've had a look at the plugins available, and I don't think that there is one that suits my needs. The plugins that I've seen either display your own latest tweets and create posts from them, or simply display the latest posts for given hashtags.

What I want to do is search for tweets containing certain keywords (for a competition), and create a post for each of these tweets - not a digest - regardless of the author. If anyone knows of a plugin that does do something similar, please let me know.

Alternatively, I guess I will have a go at modifying or extending TwitterTools or starting from scratch...

Answer (score 2):

[Twitter Tools](http://alexking.org/projects/wordpress/readme?project=twitter-tools) is one of the better Free Twitter plugins for WordPress.

- Allows you to display a number of latest tweets.
- Can dynamically create weekly/daily digest posts about the tweet
- Gives you the ability to post tweets from the WP admin interface

I've used it on a number of projects, definitely recommend.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation - giving Twitter tools a go today.